# Using php array_chunk with mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to break up an array into chunks, but it's the result of a mysql query that contains multiple values. It looks like this:

```
$minQuery = "SELECT typeName, typeID FROM  invTypes WHERE groupID = '18'";

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', $username, $password, 'sdeodyssey107');
$result = mysqli_query($con,$minQuery);
```

What I need to do is to be able to break this result up into rows of 3 at a time. I can't seem to find a way to get array_chunk to work with the multiple values, and everything I have tried with while loops ends up with me repeating the same value multiple times per row.

Anyone know a good way to handle this? The line that will be printed looks like this:

```
echo '<td align="right">' . $typeName . ': <input type="text" size="25" name="' . $typeName . '|' . $itemID . '"';if(isset($_GET["$cleanTypeName|$itemID"])) echo 'value="'.$_GET["$cleanTypeName|$itemID"].'"';echo '></td>';
```

...so I need to have both values available each time I call the function that prints those lines....

Comment: Careful, you're opening yourself up to XSS attacks.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` around any variable data you use in an HTML context.

Comment: I'm not clear on what it is that you're looking for... Could you clarify? Do you want the output table to have three columns per row? Like: `<tr> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> </tr>  <tr> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> </tr>...`

Comment: Exactly, Steven. I need to drop a <tr>, then 3 items from the mysqli_query, then a </tr>. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $i = 1;
  $count = count($result) - 3;
  echo '<tr/>';
  foreach($result as $key => $value)
  {
    if ($i % 3 === 0 && $i > 3) echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue)
    {
     echo '<td align="right">' . $value['typeName'] . ': <input type="text" size="25" name="' . $value['typeName'] . '|' . $value['itemID'] . '"';if(isset($_GET["$cleanTypeName|$itemID"])) echo 'value="'.$_GET["$cleanTypeName|$itemID"].'"';echo '></td>'; 
    }
    if ($i % 3 === 0 && $i < $count) echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
  }
  echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: this will print only 3 rows in total?